# declare key type of for in loop in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below code

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

interface PersonType {
    fname: string
    lname: string
}
const person: PersonType = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};

const newObj = {
    newobj: "new value"
}

for(const key in person) {
    urlParams.append(key, newObj[key]); //error
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-ts?utm_source=dotnew&file=/src/index.ts:0-500

how should I declare's key string in the for in loop?

Answer (score 5):

In TypeScript, `for..in` will only type the key being iterated over as a *string* - not as a key of the object being iterated over. Since `key` is typed as a string, not as `newobj`, you can't use `newObj[key]`, because the generic string doesn't exist on the type.

Use `Object.entries` instead, to extract the key and the value at once, rather than trying to go through the key alone:

```
for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(newObj) {
    urlParams.append(key, val);
}
```

Comment: wow didn't know that, thanks! btw, is there any way I can skip using interface in this case? coz in url params every value of the object property is string

Comment: You omit the interface entirely, it isn't doing anything useful. Just do `const person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};`

Comment: @JudyAllen if answer met your expectations, please approve it

Comment: @TheBicPen It sounds like you're using `in` instead of `of` - the answer uses `of`

Answer (score 0):

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

interface PersonType {
    fname: string
    lname: string
}
const person: PersonType = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};

const newObj = {
    newobj: "new value"
}

for(const key in person) {
    urlParams.append(key, newObj[key as keyof PersonType]); 
}
```

in `newObj[key]` add `as keyof PersonType`

Answer (score 0):

I will often just redeclare the key with an explicit type. Especially, if I use the key often inside the loop.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

interface PersonType {
    fname: string
    lname: string
}
const person: PersonType = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};

const newObj = {
    newobj: "new value"
}

for(const keyTemp in person) {
    const key = keyTemp as keyof PersonType; // key redeclared with type
    urlParams.append(key, newObj[key]);
}
```