# How to iterate over the properties of a mapped type with type-safety in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This seems trivial but I don't seem to be able to find the answer I'm looking for.

I have a mapped type like so:

```js
type TagTransformations = {
    [P in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]?: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap; // HTMLElementTagNameMap by the way is a built-in interface
}
```

So, as you can probably tell from the above type, I want to be able to have an object of the following shape:

```js
let transformations: TagTransformations = {
    p: 'div',
    h1: 'h2',
    button: 'span',
}
```

Basically, I want a `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` on both sides.

Now, I have a function that receives a `TagTransformations` object. In that function, I want to iterate over the properties that have been specified, and get their value. I'm doing so by using a `for...in` loop. Like so:

```js
function doTransformations(transformations: TagTransformations) {
    for (let tagName in transformations) {
        // But "tagName" is of type "string" :(
        // And "transformations[tagName]" is of type "any" :(
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the type of `tagName` inside the loop is 'string', while I expect it to be `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` or `Extract<keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap, string>` perhaps.

Also, the type of `transformations[tagName]` is "any", rather than `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`.

Is there any way I can achieve what I want here? I want to iterate over the properties of a mapped type and also have type-safety as I described.

I'm new to TypeScript so if there's anything I'm fundamentally doing wrong let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65300784/declare-key-type-of-for-in-loop-in-typescript

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. That's certainly helpful. Although even by using `for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(newObj)` the `key` is still of type `string`. I expect it to be `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` in this case, as declared in the type `TagTransformations`.

Comment: Yeah, the types of iterated keys aren't as intuitive as one would think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string If you really need it as a tag name, assert it with `as`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: Excellent. This C style hackery is exactly what I needed! I will have to find a cleaner method at some point.